# How to use type of in objects to get oddValues

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

**1.Here is the task.**

```
 Declare a function removeOddValues.
```

- @param {object} ??? - an object
- @returns {object} a new object that contains the same key/value pairs as the given object, except that any key/value pair where the value is an ODD number is removed

**2.Your code here.**

```
  function removeOddValues(obj){
   let result = {};
   for(const key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] % 2 === 0){
     result[key] = obj[key];
     return result;
   }
   else if(!isNaN(obj[key]))
    return obj;
   }
 }
```

**3.Here is the test.**

```
test(removeOddValues({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }), { b: 2 });
test(removeOddValues({ a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" }), {
a: "1",
b: "2",
c: "3",
});
// If a line gets really long, you can put key/value pairs on new lines.
```

**4.Here is the error.**

[image]

But output are supposed to be {b:2} and { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" }, not both are { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" }

Comment: you are `return` -ing within the for loop which ends the loop. Since the first case is odd you are returning the object with `return obj`  - you should only return the result after the loop.

Comment: Also, `typeof` will give you something like "number" or "string" and so doing the `%` on the string value will not be particularly useful.

Comment: The typeof those objects is 'number'. You want `parseInt(obj[key]) %2 ==0` to eliminate objects by their value. Or are you trying to eliminate by position, in which case you need a for loop not a for-in, or use your own counter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the if check. You are checking if the typeof value is divisible by 2, it will return NaN since typeof obj[key] is returning string or number and modulus of that will be NaN. Your condition in else if passes so the whole object is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more functional way of doing the same:

```js
function removeOddValues(o){
 return Object.entries(o)
   .reduce((a,[k,v])=>{
     if (typeof v==="string" || v%2===0) a[k]=v;
     return a;
   }, {});
}

console.log(removeOddValues({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }));
console.log(removeOddValues({ a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" }));
```

Comment: Thank you for your coding. This is a such advanced one!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind help, but actually i couldn't 100% understand your whole code. Could you teach me what does "a"mean in it? And why put "return" in second line of code?